# How can I make the echo command not skip the double quote

Tags: shell

I have a long script and one line of the code, is supposed to echo the name of the hostname (f is the variable which my script reads from another file):

```
echo "  ignore where match("$f", host.name)" >> /home/username/outputfile
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
ignore where match("myhostname.com", host.name)
```

But my echo script skips the ".  And I end up with this line which is missing the ":

```
ignore where match(myhostname.com, host.name)
```

Can you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the double quotes:

```
$ f="myhostname.com"
$ echo "  ignore where match(\"$f\", host.name)"
```

If will return:

```
ignore where match("myhostname.com", host.name)
```